# How to use media scanner scanFile() to scan a DocumentFile path on Android?

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I'm trying to use `scanFile()` to scan a file I have created using `DocumentFile`. It would appear that this function does not work with a `DocumentFile`'s uri/path. Is there any way to get them to work together or another method to invoke the media scanner?

```
DocumentFile myDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.myStrDir).findFile("Folder").findFile("test.mp4");

scanFile(myDir.getUri().getPath());

private void scanFile(String filePath) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext, new String[]{filePath},
                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String file, Uri fileUri) {
                        mHandler.post(mUIUpdateHandler);
                    }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that this is not necessary. I switched from files to DocumentFiles and the created DocumentFiles show up immediately without the need to invoke scanFile().